# Preciso ordenar uma lista em ordem que parece incomum

Tags: c#, .net, linq, classificação, lista

Eu tenho uma consulta e quero ordenar essa consulta pelo atributo código. Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
consulta.OrderBy(c => c.Codigo);
```

Resultado obtido:

```
1.01
1.A
14.04
14.11
22.01
3.04
30.01
4.01
40.02
```

Resultado esperado:

```
1.01
1.A
3.04
4.01
14.04
14.11
22.01
30.01
40.02
```

Comment: Isto é `string`, certo? Você pode garantir que sempre sempre neste formato e terá no máximo dois dígitos antes do ponto decimal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar [`PadLeft()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_PadLeft_System_Int32_) para alinhar o texto, mas pode precisar de algo mais complexo se o padrão não for tão linear. Complica um pouco mais resolver o alinhamento depois do ponto decimal, então teria que achar onde ele está.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<string> { "1.01", "1.A", "14.04", "14.11", "22.01", "3.04", "30.01", "4.01", "40.02" };
        foreach (var item in lista.OrderBy(i => { var partes = i.Split('.'); return partes[0].PadLeft(2) + partes[1]; })) {
            WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NU5dns). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2mToq6). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/CustomSort.cs).

Answer (score 5):

Para esse caso específico recomendo você fazer um `IComparer<T>`.

```
public class MyStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
     public int Compare(string x, string y){
        string[] xs = x.Split('.'), ys = y.Split('.');

        int x1, y1,
        comp;

        //assumi que antes do ponto sempre é um int então
        if(int.TryParse(xs[0], out x1) && int.TryParse(ys[0], out y1)){
            comp = x1.CompareTo(y1);

            return comp == 0 ? string.Compare(xs[1], ys[1]) : comp;
        }

        comp = string.Compare(xs[0], ys[0]);
        return comp == 0 ? string.Compare(xs[1], ys[1]) : comp;
    }
}
```

Aqui está um [exemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pErXYR) dele funcionando :)

Answer (score 3):

Você vai ter que percorrer a string procurando o ponto a cada registro e então ordenar ela com o código inicial e depois ordenar novamente com o código final. Um pouco chato de se fazer e, dependendo, pode consumir muito processamento, talvez seja mais fácil criar duas colunas no banco (chave composta) e remover o ponto.